# equalto query firebase angularjs giving null values

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure in firebase like this:

[image]

I wan't to query the database through child 'organization' then child 'access_points' to match SSID is equalTo Abacus and return that access_point. For that I have written this code :

```
       var ref1 = new Firebase("FIREBASEURL/organization");
   var name = ref1.child("access_points").orderByChild('SSID').equalTo('Abacus')
   .on('value', function(snap) {

  $scope.acc_pt = snap.val();

      console.log($scope.acc_pt);
  });
```

But the query is not even going to SSID and thus returning null values in console. I don't know how to query the nested nodes. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

`var ref1 = new Firebase("FIREBASEURL/organization");` here you are making reference on the organization node and "access_points" is not the direct child of that reference , the direct child is `-Kh3dXkTBUPqhs_bL5D-` your query must be :

`var name = ref1.child("-Kh3dXkTBUPqhs_bL5D-").child("access_points").orderByChild('SSID').equalTo('Abacus')`